# How to detect google,bing,yahoo crawlers with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to prevent google, bing, yahoo crawlers from getting rewritten, how can i detect them?
This does not seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|bingbot|yahoo)    [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|&)images(&|$)
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/script.php?e=$1 [NC,R]
```

I believe googlebot is capitalized (Googlebot), does this make a difference?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the search engine figures out that you've created specific content for them, you'll be penalized. If you're trying to prevent your images from being "hotlinked" from a search engine, use a robots.txt file to prevent them from listing it.

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite. Preventing search engines from getting redirected when accessing a specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteCond` looks good. Capitalization doesn't matter, because you use the `NC` (nocase) flag. The problem might be rather with the second `RewriteCond`.

You can stop all rewriting for Google and co. with this rule at the beginning

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|yahoo) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This ignores all later rules, if the user agent string is one of the mentioned crawlers.

Comment: will this prevent googlebot-images also?
Is this searching http_user_agent string, or matching exactly?

Comment: @GameDevGuru This looks for `googlebot` etc. anywhere in the user agent string. So, this will prevent googlebot, googlebot-images or googlebot-mobile.